# How to have an element fade out and another element fade in in its place on window load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a splash screen for my website and I have made a progress bar to make it look nicer. I also have some links for the user to login or register.

What I want to achieve is, right after the window loads, have the progress bar do its thing for 4 seconds then have it fade out in .5 seconds and then have the links fade in in its place in .5s for a total of 5 seconds before the user can proceed.

I have put together some code to make this work using mainly:

```
setTimeout();
```

but despite having no errors as far as both I and the Google Chrome console can tell, no visible result is produced.

How can I fix my code to work properly? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I would prefer a solution in plain JavaScript, but if there's no other way, I would be satisfied with a jQuery one too.

To help you, I have assembled a demo for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bcwtz8rr/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt to switch to jquery. FadeIn and fadeOut do it easily:

```js
$(window).load(function(){

  var t=setTimeout(function(){
  $("#progressbar").fadeOut(500);
  $("#splashscreen-links").fadeIn(500);
  },4000)
  
})
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes greenglow {
    from {
        left:-120px;
    }
    to {
        left:100%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes greenglow {
    from {
        left: -120px;
    }
    to {
        left: 100%;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes greenglow {
    from {
        left: -120px;
    }
    to {
        left: 100%;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes greenglow {
    from {
        left: -120px;
    }
    to {
        left: 100%;
    }
}

@keyframes greenglow {
    from {
        left: -120px;
    }
    to {
        left: 100%;
    }
}

#progressbar {
    /* Dimensions */
    width: 250px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    /* Positioning */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 5px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 17px;
    
    /* Styling */
    background: #E6E6E6;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius:0px;
}

#progressbar:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    top: -50%;
    height: 250%;
    position: absolute;
    animation: greenglow 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: greenglow 2s linear infinite;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #1CAE30;
}

#splashscreen-links {
    /* Text */
    color: #999999;
    font-family: "Arial";
    text-decoration: none;
    
    /* Positioning */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 5px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 17px;
    
    /* Visibility */
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<p id = "splashscreen-links"><a>Login</a>&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;<a>Register</a></p>
```

Comment: Your solution works great @Ali! I am going to wait some time in case someone has a plain-JS solution, otherwise I am going to mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Thank you. Your fiddle is wrong where there is a complex mixture of nested timeouts without any interval where you tried to clear interval. Besides there is no time logic behind the 0.1 in `opacity -= opacity * 0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You are already using CSS animations. Just keep going down that path!

```
@keyframes progresshide {
  0% {opacity: 1; display:block;  }
  80% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; display:none; }
}

@keyframes linksshow {
  0% {opacity: 0;  }
  80% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1;  }
}

#progressbar {
  animation: progresshide 5s linear forwards;
}
#splashscreen-links {
  animation: linksshow 5s linear forwards;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bcwtz8rr/3/

Comment: Will this be compatible with all browsers?

Comment: Check it. But you are already using CSS animations so if not, the other functionality would not work either.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you'd rather go JS than JQuery, it *is* still possible using `.className` to switch the class, setting up classes with transitions of the `.5s` you mentioned, and using `setTimeout` appropriately.

First, we start by introducing another two rather simple classes:

```
     .showObject {
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 1;
}
.hideObject {
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
}
```

Then, `JS` with appropriate `setTimeout` usage:

```
window.onload = function SwitchProgress() {

// Declaration
'use strict';

// Fade in
document.getElementById('progressbar').setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
document.getElementById('progressbar').className = 'showObject';

// Waiting 4s for bar animation, then fading it out
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('progressbar').className = 'HideObject';

    // .5s while the bar fades out, removing bar, displaying links 
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('progressbar').setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
        document.getElementById('splashscreen-links').setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
            // .01s for display change, links fade in
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById('splashscreen-links').className = 'showObject';
            }, 10);
    }, 990);
}, 4000);
```

};

Just wanted to note: I got this to work on Codecademy (codebits), which refreshes the file every time you make a change. JSFiddle didn't work as well. Should be fine for usage on a page that's actually going to experience proper `onload` execution.

Comment: It doesn't fade in and out. It just appears and dissapears.

Comment: It increases and decreases in ``opacity`` and alters ``display`` of each element with the required timing. Not entirely sure what you expect.